# Select value from XML node where conditions are met

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have the following xml which I want to query to turn into a flat table structure.

```
<RiskBoundReportProcess>
    <RiskBoundReport>
        <Policy key="Pol126446">
            <LineOfBusinessCode>ISR</LineOfBusinessCode>
            <AssignedIdentifier>
                <RoleCode>Insured</RoleCode>
                <Id>BP-1438</Id>
            </AssignedIdentifier>
            <RiskParticipationPercentIndicator>true</RiskParticipationPercentIndicator>
            <PolicySection>
                <PolicyProducer>
                    <RoleCode>Coverholder</RoleCode>
                    <Producer>
                        <OrganizationReferences organizationReference="Coverholder"/>
                    </Producer>
                </PolicyProducer>
                <PolicyProducer>
                    <RoleCode>Underwriter</RoleCode>
                    <Producer>
                        <Contact>
                            <PersonReferences>
                                <PersonName>
                                    <FullName>Name</FullName>
                                </PersonName>
                            </PersonReferences>
                        </Contact>
                    </Producer>
                </PolicyProducer>
                <PolicyProducer>
                    <RoleCode>Broker</RoleCode>
                    <AssignedIdentifier>
                        <RoleCode>Broker</RoleCode>
                        <Id>112</Id>
                    </AssignedIdentifier>
                    <Producer>
                        <OrganizationReferences organizationReference="BrokerOrg112"/>
                    </Producer>
                </PolicyProducer>
                <PolicyProducer>
                    <RoleCode>LondonBroker</RoleCode>
                    <ProducerReferences producerReference="Binder1">
                        <ExternalIdentifier>
                            <TypeCode>UniqueMarketReference</TypeCode>
                            <Id>UMRGoesHere</Id>
                        </ExternalIdentifier>
                        <OrganizationReferences>
                            <OrganizationName>
                                <FullName>Partners Ltd</FullName>
                            </OrganizationName>
                        </OrganizationReferences>
                        <BindingAuthorityPeriod>
                            <StartDate>2014-05-01</StartDate>
                            <EndDate>2015-04-30</EndDate>
                        </BindingAuthorityPeriod>
                    </ProducerReferences>
                    <RiskParticipationPercent>1.0000</RiskParticipationPercent>
                </PolicyProducer>
            </PolicySection>
        </Policy>
    </RiskBoundReport>
</RiskBoundReportProcess>
```

So far I have two columns. I now want to create a column for UniqueMarketReference which is found in the following node

```
RiskBoundReportProcess/RiskBoundReport/Policy/PolicySection/PolicyProducer[RoleCode="LondonBroker"]/ProducerReferences/ExternalIdentifier/[TypeCode="UniqueMarketReference"]/Id
```

How do I modifiy the SQL below to include this?

```
SELECT
    Policy.value('@key', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS PolicyId,
    Policy.value('LineOfBusinessCode[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS LineOfBusinessCode
FROM @ACORDXML.nodes('/RiskBoundReportProcess/RiskBoundReport') AS RiskBoundReport(Nodes)

CROSS APPLY RiskBoundReport.Nodes.nodes('Policy') AS Policies(Policy)
```

I will eventually return The Insured, Coverholer and Underwriter as columns too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close... The `XPath` you provided has just one `/` before `[TypeCode ...]`, which is to much.

Try it like this:

```
SELECT
    Policy.value(N'@key', N'VARCHAR(50)') AS PolicyId
   ,Policy.value(N'LineOfBusinessCode[1]', N'VARCHAR(50)') AS LineOfBusinessCode
   ,Policy.value(N'(/RiskBoundReportProcess/RiskBoundReport/Policy/PolicySection
                   /PolicyProducer[RoleCode="LondonBroker"]
                   /ProducerReferences/ExternalIdentifier[TypeCode="UniqueMarketReference"]/Id/text())[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS LondonBroker
   ,Policy.value(N'(/RiskBoundReportProcess/RiskBoundReport/Policy/PolicySection
                   /PolicyProducer[RoleCode="Underwriter"]
                   /Producer/Contact/PersonReferences/PersonName/FullName/text())[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS Underwriter
FROM @ACORDXML.nodes('/RiskBoundReportProcess/RiskBoundReport') AS RiskBoundReport(Nodes)
CROSS APPLY RiskBoundReport.Nodes.nodes('Policy') AS Policies(Policy);
```

Some of your nodes look like `1:n`-related (`<PersonReferences><PersonName>...`). This might need some extra effort (`.nodes()`)...

Comment: @Bizarrefish, I'm glad to help you, happy coding!